# Не обрабатывается Inline кнопка;

Tags: python, aiogram

есть код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(function=lambda c: c.data)
async def inlines(c):
    if c.data == 'нет':
        await bot.send_message(c.message.from_user.id, 'привет')
```

он должен обработать нажатие Inline кнопки и написать сообщение;

но он выводит ошибку, что фильтр удалён:

```
 raise NameError("Invalid filter name(s): '" + "', ".join(full_config.keys()) + "'")
NameError: Invalid filter name(s): 'function'
```

как я понимаю этот способ уже не работает;

как мне обработать callback Inline кнопок?

Comment: небольшая поправка callback.message.id, а не (callback.message.from_user.id

Comment: @kvorder зачем ему айди сообщения? Он отправляет в ЛС юзеру, а это делается по юзер айди.

Answer (score 1):

Не существует `c` и `function` ! Вместо этого `call` и `func`!
Правильное построение -

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'pgtod': # Calldata лучше писать на английском)
        await bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, 'привет')
```

Answer (score 1):

От части @Alex_Zab прав, но.. пожалуйста прекратите делать так как делаете вы. Делайте так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="нет")
async def inlines(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(callback.message.from_user.id, 'привет')
```

text проверяет то что написано в колбек дате, а если месседж хендлер, то то что написано в сообщении. Есть ещё text_startswith, text_endswith, text_contains. С чего начинается, чем заканчивается и содержит ли.

В общем не делайте этот "лямбда колл равен тру", это какой-то кошмар который пришел с телебота.